# R-ArcGIS Bridge - Interpolation with gstat library

Tags: r, interpolation, sp, inverse-distance-weighted, gstat

I have a problem with the idw or krige function from the gstat library in R. I'm trying to use the gstat library and the R-ArcGIS bridge to load a shapefile from ArcGIS into R, interpolate the data and then transform it back again. In the end I want to get a TIFF file with the interpolated grid, which I can load into ArcGIS.
Here is my script so far:

```
library(arcgisbinding)
library(sp)
library(gstat)

arc.check_product()

###--GET EXTENT AND COORDINATES FROM SHAPE--###
elev_shp <- arc.open("filepath/elev.shp")
elev_shp@extent
x_min <- 316116
y_min <- 5657570
x_max <- 317766
y_max <- 5659070

###--INPUT: LOAD DATA--###
elev_shp <- arc.select(arc.open("filepath/elev.shp"))
class(elev_shp)

###--CREATE GRID/RASTER--###
grd <- expand.grid(RW=seq(from=x_min, to=x_max, by=10), HW=seq(from=y_min, to=y_max, by=10))

###--CONVERT GRID TO SPATIAL OBJECT--###
coordinates(grd) <- ~RW+HW

###--ADD REFERENCESYSTEM TO GRID--###
proj4string(grd) <- "+proj=utm +zone=32N +datum=WGS84"
gridded(grd) <- TRUE
class (grd)
plot(grd)

##--CONVERT GIS-DATA TO SP_DATA--###
elev_shp_df <- arc.data2sp(elev_shp)
class(elev_shp_df)

bubble(elev_shp_df, zcol = "height", maxsize = 1, main = "Elevation by Points")

###--START INTERPOLATION--###
elev.idw = idw(elev_shp_df$height~1, elev_shp_df, grd)

##--CONVERT SP-DATA TO GIS-DATA--###
interpolation <- arc.sp2data(elev.idw)

###--OUTPUT: WRITE INTERPOLATION RASTER--###
arc.write("filepath", interpolation)
```

But when executing the function `idw()` I get the following error:

```
> elev.idw = idw(elev_shp_df$height~1, elev_shp_df, grd)
[inverse distance weighted interpolation]
Warnmeldungen:
1: In proj4string(d$data) :
  CRS object has comment, which is lost in output
2: In proj4string(newdata) :
  CRS object has comment, which is lost in output
3: In proj4string(newdata) :
  CRS object has comment, which is lost in outpu
```

Does someone have an idea of how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Those are "Warnings" not Errors. Does it work? Do you get the expected grid back? Unless your R is set to elevate warnings to "error" status it should work. They are probably related to recent changes in coordinate system representations in the latest versions of PROJ. Your data in arc probably has different codes to those R expects. Probably not a problem, but check.

Comment: There is quite a bit going on with the rollout of the latest version of GDAL and PROJ in how projection strings are being parsed. Just ignore the warnings or, if so inclined you can use the WKT format in defining the projection using `sf::st_crs("+proj=utm +zone=32N +datum=WGS84")`